# Launching MDT Task Sequence via litetouch.vbs, starts imaging from scratch after first reboot

Tags: winpe, mdt

I am launching a task sequence via litetouch.vbs. I RDP into a client machine, and run litetouch.vbs as follows:
wscript /i \my_host\deploymentShare$\scripts\litetouch.vbs /rulesfile:customsettings.ini

This prompts me to select the tast sequence and various options like applications, bitlocker etc.
This works perfectly if imaging a hyper-V VM.

However if imaging a physical machine, there is a problem. After WinPE is loaded, the PC restarts and starts  the imaging process from scratch. I get prompted again for the task sequence to use, etc. It just forgets what was selected before the reboot.
If I select the task sequence and options the second time, then the task sequence completes successfully.

I thought that after the reboot, the client was booting to PXE and starting the process. But it isnt. To test, I completely disabled, PXE. The problem still occurs.

So to summarize, litetouch.vbs is run from RDP, the client starts TS and loads WinPE, restarts, boots from Windows Boot Manager, then starts the imaging process anew.

Summary of what I tried:
Ive tried disabling PXE.
Ive tried removing the reboot step after loading WinPE but thats no good. It needs to reboot into WinPE to install OS. If not, I get a failure.
Im using Dell laptops. I read this article. Its not exactly what I am facing but I tried it. No change.
https://www.dell.com/support/kbdoc/en-ca/000146940/boot-manager-not-found-on-first-reboot-after-mdt-install-using-uefi

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure why Hyper-V VMs worked but laptops didnt. However, I can report that after updating from the 1903 ADK and PE, to 22H2 ADK/PE, everything now works as expected.